# How to create a wish list function in swiftUI and firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I want to search first in the favorite collection for a specific artwork ID and get all the documents where field of artwork id is equal to it. Then check in all these documents whether the user id field is equal to the current user if yes it exists and need to delete the document if not exists, I want to create a new document with current id user and artwork. this mean added to favorite list.

But I’m getting error: if one of the users click on the heart button it will be added to favorite. If other user sign in and click on the heart button for the same artwork it will not be added. only for one user.

```
//MARK: to get the fav

func checkFavorite(artwork_id: String, completion: @escaping (Bool, String) -> Void) {
    
    let collectionRef = FirebaseReference(.fav)
    let user_id = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    collectionRef.whereField("artwork_id", isEqualTo: artwork_id).getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting document: \(err)")
        } else if (snapshot?.isEmpty)! {
            completion(false, "")
        } else {
            
            for document in (snapshot?.documents)! {
                
                let uid = document.data()["uid"] as? String ?? ""
                if uid == user_id {
                    let documentId = document.documentID
                    //let isLiked = document.data()["isLiked"]
                    completion(true, documentId)
                }
               /** else {
                    completion(false, "")

                }**/
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
//MARK: Add to favorite

func addToFavorite( artwork_id: String, uid: String) {
    
    var ref: DocumentReference? = nil

    ref = FirebaseReference(.fav).addDocument(data: [
                
        "uid":uid,
        "artwork_id":artwork_id,
        "timestamp": Date(),
        "artwork": FirebaseReference(.artworks).document(artwork_id),
        "isLiked": true
        
    ]) { err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error adding document: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("Artwork fav added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
        }
    }
}
```

```
//MARK: delete Favorite

func deleteFavorite(documentID: String) {
    
    FirebaseReference(.fav).document(documentID).delete { (err) in
        
        if let err = err {
            print("Error deleting favorite: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("favorite have been deleted")
        }
    }
}
```

Here the call of the function:

```
Button(action: { self.liked.toggle()
                            
                            //if self.liked {
                             let like = Int.init(self.data.num_likes)!
                            
                            checkFavorite(artwork_id: self.data.id) { (success,docId) in
                                    if success == false {
                                        
                                        addToFavorite(artwork_id: self.data.id, uid: self.uid)
                                        FirebaseReference(.artworks).document(self.data.id).updateData(["num_likes": "\(like + 1)"
                                        
                                        ])
                                    }
                                        
                                    else {
                                        FirebaseReference(.artworks).document(self.data.id).updateData(["num_likes": "\(like - 1)"
                                            
                                        ])
                                        
                                        deleteFavorite(documentID: docId)
                                    }
                                            
                                }
                            //}
                            
                        }) {

                            Image(systemName: self.liked ? "heart.fill" : "heart" )
                                .foregroundColor(Color("Color"))
                        }
```

Comment: I found a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZilaQ2NBA1g) that can help you with this

Comment: Same issue here. Did you manage to solve this?